# AJax, How to get the value from a node in an XML file

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I want to get the stats from my XML when someone is asking for a particular name, but my javascript doesn't work like I want.>br>

Here's my XML :

```
<player> 
<forward><name>Joe</name><stats>45</stats></forward> 
<forward><name>Jack</name><stats>42</stats></forward> 
<forward><name>Peter</name><stats>34</stats></forward> 
<forward><name>Steve</name><stats>21</stats></forward>
<goalie><name>Pat</name><stats>2.34</stats></goalie>
</player>
```

Here's my HTML (ajax) :

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

function LoadDoc(vValue) {
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "player.xml",true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
  Answer(xmlhttp.responseXML, vValue);
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function Answer(doc, ParamValue) {

var counts=doc.getElementsByTagName("forward");
 for(var i=0;i < counts.length; i++){ 
  alert(counts.length)
  var vname = counts[i].getElementsByTagName('name');
  alert(vname[i].firstChild.nodeValue)
  var vstats = counts[i].getElementsByTagName('stats');
  alert(vstats[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
  if (vname[i].firstChild.nodeValue == ParamValue)
  {
        alert(stats[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
  }
 }

}
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<form> 
<input type="field" id="champ" /> 
<input type="button"        

onclick="javascript:LoadDoc(document.getElementById('champ').value);" /> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**The first ALERT is good finding 4 elements**
**the second ALERT works giving me JOE.**
**The third ALERT works giving me 45 (the number) of the stats of the first forward**

**But strangely, the alert are launch only once... I don't have 4 times the Alert, why it doesn''t turn 4 times inside the loop ?**
Any Idea of what's wrong ?
Or a better solution to find the stats ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the console for any error messages. At a glance, the line `alert(stats[i].firstChild.nodeValue);` references an undeclared variable `stats`, so if that line executes, the script should throw a ReferenceError and terminate, which would cause the alerts to fire only once.

Comment: Hi , sorry, I made a mistake for stats, it was vstats. But even If I correct this . I can't go through the loop. The loop does it once, and close after 1 loop.

Comment: Yes, after the first loop, it says : TypeError : vname[i] is undefined

Comment: Thanks Dagg Nabbit, finally I found it. with the error, I suppose that the vname[i] doesn't exist, so I replace the "i" with "0" so it's now vname[0]. For sure I'm looking the first element named "name" and not the second.

Comment: Good, glad you found it :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dagg Nabbit, finally I found it. with the error found previously, I suppose that the vname[i] doesn't exist, so I replace the "i" with "0" so it's now vname[0]. For sure I'm looking the first element named "name" and not the second.I replace the vstats[i] with vstat[0] and it works perfectly.